# DNN module package doesn't install controls

Tags: module, package, dotnetnuke

I am creating a DNN module, and have a working module based on this: http://www.subodh.com/Projects/DNN-Module.

When I install it on a DNN 5.6.2 installation, everything works fine, except the .ascx files do not copy over. If I copy the .ascx files manually, the module works fine.

My .dnn file looks like this:

```
...
<moduleDefinitions>
    <moduleDefinition>
        <friendlyName>SignUp.Control1</friendlyName>
        <defaultCacheTime>0</defaultCacheTime>
        <moduleControls>
            <moduleControl>
                <controlKey />
                <controlSrc>Control1.ascx/Control1.ascx</controlSrc>
                <supportsPartialRendering>True</supportsPartialRendering>
                <controlTitle>Control1</controlTitle>
                <controlType>View</controlType>
                <iconFile />
                <helpUrl />
                <viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
            </moduleControl>
...
        </moduleControls>
    </moduleDefinition>
</moduleDefinitions>
...
```

Specifically, Control1.ascx does not get copied to the DesktopModules/SignUp directory.

I do not get an error. Here is the relevant section of what DNN says when installing the module. I get no errors on install.

```
...
Info    Component installed successfully - Script
Info    Starting Installation - Module
Info    Module registered successfully - SignUp
Info    Component installed successfully - Module
Info    Starting Installation - Assembly
...
```

Can anyone tell me why the controls are not copying over to the appropriate directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have a mistake in `<controlSrc>` tag, maybe you mean: `<controlSrc>DesktopModules/SignUp.Control1/Control1.ascx</controlSrc>`

Also you need to mention this file in `<component type="File">`:

```
<component type="File">
  <files>
    <file>
      <path>Your Desire Path</path>
      <name>Control1.ascx</name>
    </file>
  </files>
</component>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems you have to both register the controls, and also move their files over.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ehsan's answer you can use MSBuild and Chris Hammonds template (http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com) which will create a resources zip and you have a single resources node rather than individual nodes for each file

Comment: Thanks very much. I have started using that template. It's a big help.